# UWP (XAML / C#) access method from parent Page within a programmatically added UserControl

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I've created a UWP XAML Page where I programmatically add a UserControl and then is displayed in a ContentControl.

```
UserControl control = new Views.PlayingGameScreen();
this.ContentControl.Content = control;
```

I'm wondering how I access a method in the parent Page from the UserControl.

Comment: You can cast the content property of the content control to Views.PlayingGameScreen and call method on the casted object

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to expose a property on the UserControl that the parent sets.

```
public partial class PlayingGameScreen : UserControl
{
   public ICommand Command { get; set; }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       this.Command?.Execute(null);
   }
}

//parent code, define the command with the logic to run
var command = new DelegateCommand(...);
var control = new Views.PlayingGameScreen
{
    Command = command
};
this.ContentControl.Content = control;
```

By doing it this way, the parent sets the Command and the UserControl doesn't need to know what the hosting parent is and there is no global class the UserContol uses. This is a completely decoupled solution.

Bonus, setup the Command as a DependencyProperty and then it can be assigned in xaml as well. You can bind the Command to your ViewModel and the ViewModel will be the Page's ViewModel.

```
<uc:PlayingGameScreen Command="{x:Bind SomeCommand}"/>
```

I've tried lots of different ways and this is my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

From my little experience with UWP (1 app and counting :D):
You can keep a reference of your ParentPage in a static property of a class, let's name it `PagesGateway.cs`

The static class code:

```
public static class PagesGateway
{
public static ParentPage ParentPage {get; set;}
}
```

Then in you code behind ParentPage, you'll need to set the reference:

```
    public partial ParentPage:Page
    {
       public ParentPage{
       PagesGateway.ParentPage = this;
    }

}
```

This way you'll have access to `ParentPage` instance methods anywhere.
But I have a feeling that's not the best practice out there. But i use this a lot to access my `ViewModels` from anywhere, and it work perfectly, but you have to take into account that it void the re-usability of a ViewModel